# How to transfer data with selected checkbox in datagrid after button click? C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have 2 tables namely `Pending.dbo` and `Approved.dbo`. I have used tabcontrol. The first tab contains `"Pending datagridview"` with `checkbox` and `btnApprove`. The second tab named `"Approved"` is just a read-only datagridview.

What I want is that when I click `btnApprove`, the data selected by `checkbox` in `"Pending datagridview"` will transfer to the table `Approved.dbo`.

Is it possible? As of now, this is my codes:

`language: c#`

```
private void btnApproved_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true select row).ToList();
        foreach (DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            using (var connect = sqlcon.getConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("COMMAND TO TRANSFER DATA??????"))
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PS. Sorry for my bad english and explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Does Pending datagridview contain only one checkbox? Do you mean when this single checkbox is checked the entire data of the datagridview will be transferred to the Approved.dbo table?

Comment: No. every row on the Pending datagridview has its own checkbox. And the selected checkbox will be transferred to the Approved.dbo. @Abhishek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be done something like this :-

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" 
                + pendingdataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +", " 
                + pendingdataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +");";
            comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to transfer selected rows to database then replace for loop part with

```
for(int i = 0; i < pendingdataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(!pendingdataGridView.Rows.Selected[i])
        Continue;

    StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" 
                + pendingdataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +", " 
                + pendingdataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +");";
    comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and then for binding values from database to `Approvedgridview`

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

// Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
DataTable table = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(table);
Approvedgridview.DataSource = table;
```

- `selectCommand` :  query for retrieving values from database
- `connectionString` : your database connection string

Comment: I think Paul only wants to transfer those rows which are selected in first tab

Comment: the tableName is the second table right? thanks! will try now!

Comment: you right Abhishek. only the selected rows will be transferred on button click. table to table.

Comment: will the data from Pending.dbo will be deleted?

Comment: @PaulEmmanuelAustria you want to delete those selected values from pendinggridview after saving it to database..? From hwere you want to delete.?

Comment: anyway its pending. when the end user view the table for pending and approved it, the data will be transferred in approved.dbo. or can i change its status from pending to approved..

Comment: @PaulEmmanuelAustria What you exactly needed.? You have got the answer for this question right. So ask your next question in separate thread in detail.So it will be easy to help you..!

Comment: my question involves the word "TRANSFER".. which means delete from first table to put on the second table. Ok. Will create another. Thanks! I just used your codes.

Comment: Then no worries you just write the logic to delete from pendinggridview after inserting the values into database